# Existe alguma maneira de limpar o ecrã sem ser fazer ciclo com '\n' ?

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber se existe outras possibilidades para além de por exemplo executar uma série de '\n'.

```
public void clrscrn(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) 
        System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas possibilidades que conheço:

```
final String sisOpe = System.getProperty("os.name");

if (sisOpe.contains("Windows")){
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");

}else{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
}
```

ou

```
System.out.print("\u001b[2J");
System.out.flush();
```

Comment: Vantagens e desvantagens de cada  ?

Comment: Sinceramente não sei Jorge. Mas ouvi sobre a primeira ser muito *feia*. Talvez por invocar um comando do cmd.